# pointer address initialization on for loop not as expected in c

Tags: c, string, loops, pointers

I'm trying to loop through a string by using a pointer and `[]` for the string, and the pointer should get on each iteration the char address, from tail to head:

```
int main(void)
{
    char* s = "somestring";
    char* s_p;
    int len = strlen(s);
    for (s_p = &s[len - 1]; s_p = &s[1]; s_p--)
    {
        //do something
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem I have, is that at the point of the `for` initialization, `s_p` is getting the address of the second index of `s`, hence `s[1]`, for instance, if `"somestring"` is located in `0x00d97be0`, then the address `s_p` points to is: `0x00d97be1` `("omestring")`, and my intention was that `s_p` start from `0x00d97be9` `"g"`.
What am I missing here?

P.S.
When I'm writing `s_p = &s[len - 1];` before the loop, I indeed get `s_p=0x00d97be9` `"g"`, as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop condition should use comparison operator, not assignment operator `=`.
I guess the intention was to use `!=`.

```
s_p = &s[1]   -->   s_p != &s[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Though the answer provides you the correction, for future reference I would add that using extra warning flags would have saved you the hassle.

For example, with gcc, the compiler flag `-Wall` would have rendered you the following warning:

> ```
> warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
> 8 |     for (s_p = &s[len - 1]; s_p = &s[1]; s--)
>   |                             ^~~
> ```

Comment: How can I add it?

Comment: @IntToThe It deppends, what tools are you using to compile your program?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: @IntToThe, in the solution explorer, right click on the file, select properties, navigate to C/C++, Command Line and in the Additional Options text box write `/Wall`, though I believe `/W4` may suffice, then you can check the error list in Visual Studio in bottom, select the Error List separator, it should also add squiggles to undeline the problem code, when you hover it, it shows you the problem.

Comment: @IntToThe, you can also do this in the General tab of properties mentioned above, in the Warning level line, you can select several warning levels, from /W0 to /Wall.